# XFCE unity command mistake

Tags: unity, xfce, xfwm4

Few days ago I erroneously run the command `unity` within XFCE. As expectable, what happened was that Unity started (it's a Ubuntu XFCE).

I hoped to solve the problem by just restarting the device, but, at the startup, unfortunately:

- I lost the title bar of every window (the one containing also the minimizing, maximizing and closing window buttons)
- It is like if my session was automatically saved, because now every time I log in I got the same configuration I haved at that time (3 terminals opened, firefox and thunar)
- Plus, doing `atl-f4` was not working for closing the programs opened.

I found out that `xfwm4` reset the title bar, and I was then able to either close the windows by pushing the small "x" button on the top bar or by doing the shortcut `atl-f4`.

What did `unity` command exactly screw up on my XFCE environment? The problem is still there, since everytime I log in, I still face the same 3 above-mentioned problems.

Thanks